# How to drop all collections via mongodb and node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to node.js and mongodb and I have the following problem:
I need to drop all collections from my mongodb from node.js file. I have such a function:

```
service.dropCollections = function(db, colls){
  for(var i = 0; i < colls.length; i++){
    var name = colls[i].name;
    db.dropCollection(name, function(err) {
        if(!err) {
            console.log( name + " dropped");
        } else {
            console.log("!ERROR! " + err.errmsg);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

And I am using it in the following function:

```
service.clearDB = function() {
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
, format = require('util').format;    

  MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/shiny_d', function(err, db){
    if(err) throw err;
    db.collectionNames(function(err, collections){
        if(!err){
            service.dropCollections(db, collections);
        } else {
            console.log("!ERROR! "+ err.errmsg);
        }
        service.showCollections();
    });
  });
}
```

As an output I have

> !ERROR! ns not found
>
> shiny_db.physicalinfos

Dunno what to do right now. I'll be very thankful for your help.

Comment: Don't delete anything that starts with `system` as those are reserved for use by MongoDB.

Comment: Can you tell me hove to avoid them?

Comment: just check to see if the string starts with `system`.

Comment: like this? `if (name.substring(0, 6) == "system")`

Comment: Nearly, it's `substring(from, to)`, so `(0, 5)` and using `===` would be considered best practice for JavaScript.

Comment: well, I've tested it, and the result is following: 
lets assume we have variable `var str = "system.name";`
if we will prompt `console.log(str.substring(0, 5));` output will be `syste`, but if we will prompt `console.log(str.substring(0, 6));` output will be `system`. That's confused me a bit when I've learned it, but it how `substring` works. And yes, I made mistake, I meant `if (name.substring(0, 6) !== "system")`

Comment: Oh yeah, duh, it's `to`, but not including `to`. :)

Comment: Anyway you helped to me solve my issue, so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer. First of all I've made mistake in my connection it should be like following: `'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/shiny_db'`. The second mistake was in the name of collection. It was like `'db_name.coll_name'`, that's why `db.dropCollection(name, callback)` couldn't find particular collection and because of it I had mistake `ns not found`. So I've used following mechanism to separate db_name from coll_name:

`var name = colls[i].name.substring('shiny_db.'.length);` and I've added checking for "system" collection.

Final code looks like following:

```
service.clearDB = function() {
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
    , format = require('util').format;    

    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/shiny_db', function(err, db) {
        if(err) throw err;
        db.collectionNames(function(err, collections){
            if(!err){
                service.dropCollections(db, collections);                
            } else {
                console.log("!ERROR! "+ err.errmsg);
            }
        });
    });
}
service.dropCollections = function(db, colls){
    for(var i = 0; i < colls.length; i++){
        var name = colls[i].name.substring('shiny_db.'.length);

        if (name.substring(0, 6) !== "system") {
            db.dropCollection(name, function(err) {
                if(!err) {
                    console.log( name + " dropped");
                } else {
                    console.log("!ERROR! " + err.errmsg);
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log(name + " cannot be dropped because it's a system file");
        }    
    } 
}
```

Hope it will help someone!

Answer (score 8):

Ain't it more faster, easier and less error prone if you just drop the entire database?

```
db.dropDatabase();
```

At least from the Mongo CLI, whenever you access an inexistent DB, it'll be persisted the soon you create data. That's the same as dropping all collections from it.

I haven't tried MongoDB for anything except studying yet, so I don't know much about permissions. So, probably the only problem of dropping the entire DB would be the permissions of your users that would be lost (I believe).

If this script you're trying to create is not for production, then you're good to go with dropping the DB.

Comment: well, it wasn't my goal ;)

Answer (score 0):

[`listCollections`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/collections.html#list-existing-collections) gives you an array of collection names as strings.

It looks like you may be confusing it with something that returns an array of collection objects like maybe [`db.collections()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/collections.html#list-collections)

Comment: But what the difference what to use for defining a collection name? I just  need names of collections to use them as arguments in `db.dropCollection(name, callback)`

Comment: if it gives you back an object you need to use obj.name to get the name. if it gives you back names, you shouldn't use name.name.

Comment: Well, I've checked what `collectionNames` returns, and it returns a collection with object, that have a field "name". But your answer bring me one idea that was successful, thanks a lot!